# Email receiver proxy in wso2 esb 5.0.0 is not working

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I have created email receiver proxy in WSO2-ESB5.0, proxy is connecting to email box and and I am seeing text in the logs "Processing message # : 1 in same thread".

But nothing is getting printed in the body of the proxy where I am expecting proxy should read the email body and pass to insequence of the proxy.

And also emails are not MOVED OR DELETED when I set the properties ActionAfterProcess to MOVE/DELETE.

Answer (score 0):

Here is sample of my proxy:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="MailTransportProtocolIMAP"
       transports="mailto"
       startOnLoad="true"
       statistics="enable"
       trace="enable">
   <description/>
   <target>
      <inSequence>

         <log level="full">
         </log>
         <log category="ERROR">
            <property name="emailBody" expression="$body/*"/>
         </log>
         <drop/>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <log category="ERROR">
            <property name="emailBody" expression="$body/*"/>
         </log>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
   </target>
   <parameter name="mail.imap.socketFactory.class">javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory</parameter>
   <parameter name="mail.imap.starttls.enable">false</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.mail.ContentType">application/xml</parameter>
   <parameter name="mail.imap.host">outlook.74.net</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.mail.Address">abc@abc.com</parameter>
   <parameter name="mail.imap.user">abc123</parameter>
   <parameter name="mail.imap.socketFactory.port">993</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.mail.ActionAfterFailure">DELETE</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.mail.ActionAfterProcess">DELETE</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.PollInterval">2</parameter>
   <parameter name="mail.imap.port">995</parameter>
   <parameter name="mail.imap.ssl.enable">false</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.mail.MoveAfterFailure">Inbox/Failed</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.mail.Folder">Inbox/TestInbox</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.mail.MoveAfterProcess">Inbox/Processed</parameter>
   <parameter name="mail.imap.fetchsize">2</parameter>
   <parameter name="mail.imap.socketFactory.fallback">false</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.mail.Protocol">imap</parameter>
   <parameter name="mail.imap.password">abc123!</parameter>
</proxy>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see some issues here

you have in one hand

```
   <parameter name="transport.mail.ActionAfterFailure">DELETE</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.mail.ActionAfterProcess">DELETE</parameter>
```

and on another hand you try to move to a folder after process or failure

```
   <parameter name="transport.mail.MoveAfterFailure">Inbox/Failed</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.mail.MoveAfterProcess">Inbox/Processed</parameter>
```

So either you should remove all those four lines (default behaviour is "REMOVE") or change to

```
   <parameter name="transport.mail.ActionAfterFailure">MOVE</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.mail.ActionAfterProcess">MOVE</parameter>
```

In order to move processed files

Fetch size sounds really small to me, could you try a higher value like

```
<parameter name="mail.imap.fetchsize">1024</parameter>
```

Then I assume Inbox/TestInbox is existing and you successfully connect to the mailbox. Are you sure that the message content type is application/xml (could you simply use plain/text for instance).
Could you also try

```
<property name="senderAddress" expression="get-property('transport', 'From')"/>
<log level="custom">
    <property name="Sender Address" expression="get-property('senderAddress')"/>
</log>
```

To see if you can get the sender address.